# Running easy_install along with / before python setup.py sdist

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools, tox

I have a dependency package that must install with `easy_install`

`easy_install deps/my_deps_package.egg`

My current steps:

- Create a virtual environment
- Install dependency: `easy_install deps/my_deps_package.egg`
- Run the setup and install the package: `python setup.py sdist && pip install -e .[dev] dist/my_package.tar.gz`

It worked fine now, but I can not add `my_deps_package.egg` to `requirements.txt` and I want when running `python setup.py sdist`, it should install all of it.

I'm using `tox` for running the tests and seems it's don't have option to run `easy_install` before install package.

Is there anyway to using `easy_install` along with python setup.py process or with `tox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tox` typically uses one install tool/command which can be set using `install_command`. It will pass both the packages defined in `deps` and your package to that [install_command](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#conf-install_command) (defaults to `python -m pip install {opts} {packages}(ARGV)`). Having two different install commmands is therefor impossible. Hence we will have to create a workaround.

An approach could be:

1. Turn off regular installation flow. (`skipp_install = true`)
2. Use commands_pre to perform all installation commands in the correct order.
3. Use regular `commands` for whatever you want to do.

```
[testenv]
skip_install = true
commands_pre = 
    easy_install deps/my_deps_package.egg
    python setup.py sdist
    python -m pip install -e .[dev] dist/my_package.tar.gz
commands =
    pytest
```

This way you still achieve some separation of concerns as your installation commands only live in `commands_pre`.

Bonus:

```
[testenv:something]
# This should inherite the pre_commands from [testenv]
commands = 
    # Do something else :)
    ls
```